# What is the ADO.net parameterization for "Now"?

Tags: ado.net, parameterized-query

I have an application that is storing values in a Jet Blue database. I build, and issue, a query *such as*:

```
INSERT INTO Hisotry (DeathDate, Frob, Grobber)
VALUES (Now(), "Unilatteral phase detractor's", "Sinusoidal depleneration")
```

Now I'm migrating to a different database, and I figured it might be time to use that <strike>pain in the ass</strike> fancy parameterization:

```
void Trunnions(DbConnection connection, String frob, String grobber)
{
   String sql = 
         "INSERT INTO Hisotry (DeathDate, Frob, Grobber)" + "\r\n"+
         "VALUES (@deathDate, @frob, @grobber)";

   using (DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
      cmd.CommandText = sql;
      DbParameter param;

      param = cmd.CreateParameter();
      param.Name = "@deathDate";
      param.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
      param.Value = "Now()";
      cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

      param = cmd.CreateParameter();
      param.Name = "@frob";
      param.DbType = DbType.StringFixedLength;
      param.Value = frob;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

      param = cmd.CreateParameter();
      param.Name = "@grobber";
      param.DbType = DbType.String;
      param.Value = grobber;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Of course, trying to use `Now()` as a value for a `DbType.DateTime` parameter is not valid.

I could have used:

```
param = cmd.CreateParameter();
param.Name = "@deathDate";
param.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
param.Value = DateTime.Now;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

except that's not correct - it uses the local machine's clock rather than the server's.

The only reason I ask is because I don't know what the new database engine's syntax for `Now()` is. I know some can use:

- `getdate()`
- `getutcdate()`
- `SYSDATETIME()`
- `SYSUTCDATETIME()`
- `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`
- `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`
- `NOW()`
- `LOCALTIMESTAMP()`

And I remember it took me *hours* in 2008 to figure out what **Jet Blue** used. i'd rather have the ADO.net solution.

Comment: Do you have control over the schema? If yes then just make the column with a default of Now() (or the equivalent of it in the db engine) and don't insert it at all.

Comment: @ChrisWue i do not. Besides, i'm trying to find out how to parameterize queries that are currently hand-crafted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server:

1. Change the `"Now()"` to `DateTime.Now()` without the quotes
2. Change the insert statement to be:

   ```
   String sql = 
       "INSERT INTO Hisotry (DeathDate, Frob, Grobber)" + "\r\n"+
       "VALUES (GetDate(), @frob, @grobber)";
   ```

Comment: This looks like the only solution, and a reasonable one at that. The parameter `DeathDate` isn't *really* a parameter; it's a constant.